# Routing Error. The component for route 'key1' must be a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using react-native-router-flux package for routing and it seems something is wrong. I have seen other similar problem but none of the solution worked for me.

Please help...

Here is my code:-

routes.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Router, Stack, Scene} from 'react-native-router-flux';
import Login from './pages/login';
import Signup from './pages/signup';

class Routes extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <Router>
                <Stack key='root' hideNavBar = {true}>
                    <Scene key = "login" Component={Login} Title="Login" initial={true}/>
                    <Scene key = "register" Component={Signup} Title="Register" />
                </Stack>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}

export default Routes;
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import Routes from './src/routes';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar backgroundColor="#2f4f4f" barStyle="light-content" />
        <Routes />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#70a9a9',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
export default App;
```

I am new to react native and looking forward for the solution.

The Error I'm facing is listed below:-

```
Error: The component for route 'login' must be a React component. For example:

import MyScreen from './MyScreen';
...
login: MyScreen,
}

You can also use a navigator:

import MyNavigator from './MyNavigator';
...
login: MyNavigator,
}

This error is located at:
    in Router (at routes.js:9)
    in Routes (at App.js:10)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in App (at registerRootComponent.js:17)
    in RootErrorBoundary (at registerRootComponent.js:16)
    in ExpoRootComponent (at renderApplication.js:34)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:33)
- node_modules/react-navigation/src/routers/validateRouteConfigMap.js:23:12 in <unknown>
- node_modules/react-navigation/src/routers/validateRouteConfigMap.js:15:21 in validateRouteConfigMap
- ... 25 more stack frames from framework internals
```

Comment: What errors do you have?

Comment: here is the error:-

Comment: Error: The component for route 'key1' must be a React component. For example:

import MyScreen from './MyScreen';
...
key1: MyScreen,
}

You can also use a navigator:

import MyNavigator from './MyNavigator';
...
key1: MyNavigator,
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In routes.js on these lines : 
`<Scene Key = "login" Component={Login} Title="Login" initial={true}/>
 <Scene Key = "register" Component={Signup} Title="Register" />` 

You're capitalizing `Key` and therefore React thinks you're appending a component and that's why it throws the error to import the component.
Lowercase the `key` and it should work fine. Sorry I couldn't comment instead, but I don't have enough rep.

Comment: Thanks so much it worked. But now i am getting same error with route 'login'. can you help i have updated error and the code as well